# How can I optimize searching in the vector of custom class?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm modding a game to play different sounds for certain occasions (like Christmas, Halloween, etc.).

I created a custom class and a vector of elements:

```
class remappedAudioFromKeepAlive {
public:
    std::string Search = "";
    std::string ReplaceTo = "";
    bool MultiplayerOnly = false;
};
vector<remappedAudioFromKeepAlive> Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive;
char Stored_Tmp_NewAudio_String[256];
```

This new function is called every time the game is trying to play a sound:

```
std::string StringFromEax = currentEAX;
if (StringFromEax.length() > 2 && StringFromEax.length() < 41) {
    //Loop
    for (size_t iha = 0; iha < Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive.size(); iha++) {
        if (StringFromEax == Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive[iha].Search) {
            bool ContinueThisAudio = true;
            if (Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive[iha].MultiplayerOnly) {
                if ((Stored_Current_Game_Type_SP0_MP1 == 1) || (Stored_Currently_Really_in_MP_Lobby1 == 1)) {
                    ContinueThisAudio = true;
                }
                else {
                    ContinueThisAudio = false;
                }
            }
            if (ContinueThisAudio) {
                std::snprintf(Stored_Tmp_NewAudio_String, std::size(Stored_Tmp_NewAudio_String), "%s", Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive[iha].ReplaceTo.c_str());
                return (LPVOID*)Stored_Tmp_NewAudio_String;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: A bit updated version thanks to comments below:

```
extern "C" LPVOID * Change_Sounds_on_Events(int CallType, char* currentEAX) {
    if (currentEAX != NULL && Have_At_least_1_Remapped_Audio) {
        std::string StringFromEax = currentEAX;
        if (StringFromEax.length() > 2 && StringFromEax.length() < 41) {
            for (auto const& remap : Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive) {
                if (StringFromEax == remap.Search) {
                    if (remap.MultiplayerOnly) {
                        if ((Stored_Current_Game_Type_SP0_MP1 == 1) || (Stored_Currently_Really_in_MP_Lobby1 == 1)) {
                        
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    Str_Stored_Tmp_NewAudio_String = remap.ReplaceTo;
                    return reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(Str_Stored_Tmp_NewAudio_String.data());
                    break; //pointless, I know.
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works flawlessly (different sounds are played). However, I am not sure if this method is optimal. It has to loop by all elements in `Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive` vector, and then compare strings to make sure it's the one intended. I would like to optimize it as much as possible to prevent unnecessary CPU load. Should I use something else? Would some `vector<map<>>` be more optimal in this case?

Comment: How many elements are typically in the vector?  A binary search can make searching faster, but it requires the data set be sorted, which can add extra computation power.  A linear traversal of a small vector on the other hand is simple to code, and really easy for CPUs to work with.

Comment: Unrelated: This would benefit from range-based for loops. It'd be a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for replies. The array will have around 20 elements on Christmas, and in the other days 0 (an additional `Have_At_least_1_Remapped_Audio` boolean is used, so this function just won't execute).

The `Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive` is usually updated 1 time, on game start (it gets values from the Internet), so I can sort it, or add extra optimizations with no limit, especially because updating `Vector_remappedAudioFromKeepAlive` array would be in a different thread than the one that game uses for itself.

Comment: With so few (20) elements, it is unlikely that sorting will offer much. Even for Xmas.

Comment: @Damien yeah, I thought the same. The problem is it's an old game that uses a single thread for everything (and it already causes FPS loss), so I wanted to make it as optimal as possible. This function might be called pretty often, with different sounds. 99% of them won't need to be changed, but the array will be still looping ~20 times.

Comment: @Mona You should be using a tool like `perf` to analayze the program and find out where the performance bottle necks are.  Working on those should give you the biggest benifits.  You also need to consider how much data your program is crunching, and figure out if the specs of the system even allow that much throughput.  Here is a good video about these techniques: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EWejmkKlxs

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver. I know I could test the performance, but just to be honest, the game is not open source, so I'm modding by attaching a custom DLL. It's hard to test such a small array performance in a game where load might differ during every test. For example AI players might do different actions, animals might move differently, weather might change, etc. This is why I mostly counted on some generic tips if the method I used  is optimal enough, or there is some faster alternative with std::search, std::map, etc.

Comment: It's really hard to up performance just using general guidelines like that.  You really need hard data to make the right decisions.  Take `vector` vs `list`.  `list` has `O(1)` insertion in the middle, but a vector will still out perform it in many cases: https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html

Comment: Start by cleaning up the code: https://godbolt.org/z/6WTG1hh7T

Comment: @ViralTaco_ thanks for the tips, I'll update a few things based on it, however I already see that it can't be that simplified. `currentEAX` is a `char*` (address pointer pushed by the game to call the DLL function, using the assembly, not a string). The other variables are ints, not bools, since they might be "-1" if a check function earlier failed, etc. The return value must be an address to memory that never changes (that's why copying to char[256]), because game might re-use it at any time. Modding this way is a bit risky (crashes) that's why I prefer to have a longer code than simplify it.

Comment: Perhaps it is a limitation of the environment you are working in, but can you not use `std::unordered_map<std::string, remappedAudioFromKeepAlive>`? where the key is the contents currently held in the `Search` field of `remappedAudioFromKeepAlive`. (You could even remove this field as it would become redundant.)

Comment: @idz, Yes. I can use it this way. Would that be a better choice? What should I then use to search for the `Search` in that vector?

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416278/2517973 so maybe for such a small vector like mine (max. 30) it's better to use as it is?

Comment: @mona, perhaps, for a vector that small it is not worth it. (Might be worth a quick experiment though).

Comment: @idz So I tested it by running 3 separate functions, using: Vector, Unordered Map, Map. I used different processes, because with /O2 optimizations VS profiler was showing bad function names. I did a loop 1000000 x 12, searching in array of 24 elements. I repeated it few times to make sure results are similar. For vector it took 9.49 sec, Unordered Map: 5,14 sec, Normal Map: 8,78 sec. So it seems like during the big loop the unordered map is faster. However it's still hard to predict how that would perform in game where it might not be as good cached as during the test :)

Comment: Either way, executing it 12 million times took just a few seconds. The game probably won't call this function more than 10 000 times during the session, so I would guess it's really irrelevant which method is used.